# Block user after 3 attempts of login

Tags: geoserver, security

Do you know if there is a way to block a user after 3 attempts of login?

I was looking for information about but I haven't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

That is not one of the current options GeoServer provides to [prevent brute-force login attempts](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/auth.html#brute-force-attack-prevention).

If you would like to [make](http://geoserver.org/comm/) or [sponsor](http://geoserver.org/support/) an enhancement please talk to the developers on the GeoServer developers list.